# Increment an element's value through JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I have a like system on my website; and when somebody clicks the like button, I want the number of likes to go up 1 dynamically.

For this; I used an Ajax call which works fine.
Once the Ajax call is past, I want it to increment the elements value by one :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.likebutton').on('click', function() {     
    var a = $(this).attr('name');           
    var b = a.slice(4, 99);                 
    var c = "opim" + b;
    var d = 1;
    $.post('like.php', {i: b}, function(data) {
      $('.likebutton[name=' + a +']').replaceWith( "<i name=\"like$i\" class=\"fa fa-heart likebuttono thisi3\" style=\"color:red\"></i></br>Aimé!" );  
      document.getElementById(c).innerHTML = parseInt(document.getElementById(c).innerHTML,10) + d;
    });
  });
});
```

This works; but sometimes, instead of adding 1, it adds 2 or 3 to the number of likes.

Can anybody explain why it does this and how to fix this ?

Comment: You're going to need to post more code than that, as that line of code will not add more than `1`.

Comment: The only reason for that is the code bit is executed 2 or 3 times

Comment: may be people are double clicking (or triple clicking?) on the like button. I suggest you disable the button when clicked once.

Comment: So if somebody does three rapid clicks, you'll make 3 separate posts and each one will increment the counter.

Comment: @Pointy No, just one click and it adds randomly 1,2,3 or even 4 .

Comment: Have you tried adding `console.log()` calls to trace the clicks and the `$.post()` callbacks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I may suggest you to take advantage of the data attributes.

Because I do not know your HTML code I propose you the following code in order to stop from clicking more than one.

```js
$(function () {
  $('.likebutton').on('click', function (e) {
    // get the AlreadyClicked data attribute
    var aClicked = $(this).data('AlreadyClicked');

    // if yet defined stop
    if (aClicked !== undefined) {
      alert('Already clicked!');
      e.preventDefault();
      return;
    }
    // define it
    $(this).data('AlreadyClicked', true);


    var a = $(this).attr('name');
    var b = a.slice(4, 99);
    var c = "opim" + b;
    var d = 1;
    $.post('like.php', {i: b}, function (data) {
      $('.likebutton[name=' + a + ']').replaceWith("<i name=\"like$i\" class=\"fa fa-heart likebuttono thisi3\" style=\"color:red\"></i></br>Aimé!");
      document.getElementById(c).innerHTML = parseInt(document.getElementById(c).innerHTML, 10) + d;
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.1.min.js"></script>

<button class="likebutton" name="name......">I Like</button>
```

Another solution could be based on [one](http://api.jquery.com/one/): after the first click the event handler stops.

```
      $('.likebutton').one('click', function (e) {
            var a = $(this).attr('name');
            var b = a.slice(4, 99);
            var c = "opim" + b;
            var d = 1;
            $.post('like.php', {i: b}, function (data) {
                $('.likebutton[name=' + a + ']').replaceWith("<i name=\"like$i\" class=\"fa fa-heart likebuttono thisi3\" style=\"color:red\"></i></br>Aimé!");
                document.getElementById(c).innerHTML = parseInt(document.getElementById(c).innerHTML, 10) + d;
            });
        });
```